# Продублировался ответ

Tags: дефект

Когда я внес правку в ответ их почему-то стало 2 штуки.

Ссылка на вопрос: [В каких браузерах и на каких устройствах проверять адаптивный сайт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715368/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

Comment: И никаких подтверждений сего факта? Можно закрывать вопрос как нельзя воспроизвести

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715368/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82 я удалил, могу восстановить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Между публикациями ответов [прошло более двух минут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/715368/timeline):

> [image: timeline]

Это скорее похоже на какие-то проблемы с доступом к сайту. Может инет пропадал, или еще что. Хотя можно допустить и проблемы со стороны сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы пишете ответ, черновик сохраняется и потом восстанавливается в новых вкладках.

Возможно, у вас было две вкладки с ответом. Вы опубликовали первую, потом перепутали вторую со страницей редактирования, отредактировали и тоже сохранили.

Comment: Но тогда кнопка под сообщением будет "Отправить ответ", а не "Сохранить изменения".

Comment: @alexolut верно, но можно и не заметить по привычке.

Comment: по привычке «не замечать»? :)

Comment: @alexolut я почти иногда не жму эту кнопку. Обычно табом переключаюсь на строку меток и жму Enter.